# How to send the location object on whatsapp using twilio?

Tags: python, twilio

can I send a location using MessagingResponse?

when i try the below approach i get
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'persistent_action'

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    if request.values.get('Latitude'):
        lat = request.values.get('Latitude')
        long = request.values.get('Longitude')
        location = 'geo:'+lat+','+long
        loc = [location]
        msg.persistent_action(loc)
        return str(resp)
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

Comment: Can you confirm the version of your Twilio Helper Library is 6.33.1 or greater? https://github.com/twilio/twilio-python/blob/main/CHANGES.md#2019-11-13-version-6331, `pip show twilio`.

Comment: Version: 6.45.4

Comment: Is there any method to send location?

Answer (score 1):

It appears based on the documentation, that the only way to send location via WhatsApp, at least currently, is via the REST API.

[Location Messages with WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/message-features#location-messages-with-whatsapp)

- See code example: "Send a WhatsApp message with location information"

[How To Send Location Details on WhatsApp in Node JS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-location-details-whatsapp-node-js)